# Posting using Curl and php link error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm having issues posting to facebook using php & cURL I have posted my code to pastebin

http://pastebin.com/pQdXq0Pi

The link is the issue. If I use the google shortened url the post doesn't show on the feed. If I change to the long url the post will show.

confused...

obviously I have removed the access token and changed the other variables to just names.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook needs to be able to follow through the redirect if it cannot, then no data will be scraped.

`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FJ2fwI`

As opposed to

`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=bit.ly%2F169bOjM`

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i can follow the shortened url and it does have the http:// included so i'm still unsure...

Comment: @NetEffect if the debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) cannot get the body, then it will not work

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is that the short url involve a redirect ...
try add

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
to follow the redirect

Comment: my guess was wrong .. as phwd say it is Facebook that have to follow the redirect , sure:)

Comment: 'link' => "http : // goo.gl/J2fwI", this doesn't work BUT 'link' => "http : // google.com", this works